# How to call an async function after state updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I faced problems in understanding the concept of Async calls.

My state: `sentence: { author: '', context: '', date: '' }`

Then I have a function that updates a state in Redux:

```
edit(author, date) {
    let { sentence } = this.props;
    this.props.updateAuthor(sentence, author);
    this.props.updateDate(sentence, date)
}
```

These update methods are different actions and has different reducers.

After the state attributes updated, I want to send data to the server by this:

```
function uploadToServer() {
    this.props.upload(this.props.sentence);
}
```

I got lost in how to call upload function after updates are finished.

Comment: You should do that the other way around, first upload the sentence to the server and then if the response is successful resolve promise and update the state.

Right now, if You're updating only reducer, without making a request to server with updateAuthor and updateDate you don't have to wait for reducer before uploading.

Comment: actually, my state is much bigger than this and inside object I have different arrays of data, and before uploading, to the server, I need to read some other attributes like id's and some of those arrays and then chunk it, cause server have different URL's for each chunk.

Comment: You can use lifecycle method: *componentWillReceiveProps()*. Everytime your connected reducer will get updated, you will get information about new props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to make use of `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle methods to check if the new props have the changes you want made, and then do `this.props.upload` from there. Something like

```
componentWillReceiveProps (newProps) {
  // check if your state is updated with the attributes
  // this function will get called when it's going to receive new props,
  // in this case, when the redux store gets changed
  // this.props will be the unchanged props, newProps will be the changed props
  // then do this.props.upload()
}
```

Comment: yes, thanks it is a better approach to have updates at receiveProps. I had tried it before but was making mistake at the comparison of props and nextProps.

Answer (score 1):

Make both updates in the same function and pass a callback to this function:

```
edit(author, date) {
  const { sentence, updateAuthorAndDate } = this.props
  updateAuthorAndDate(sentence, author, date, this.uploadToServer)
}
```

Then in `updateAuthorAndDate`, just call the callback when the update is done:

```
updateAuthorAndDate(sentence, author, date, uploadToServer) {
  // update the author
  // update the date
  // then call the callback when the updates are done:
  uploadToServer()
}
```

Be careful if you use `setState` (probably not if you use Redux). `setState` is asynchronous so you need to call the callback in the second parameter:

```
this.setState({ ... }, /* called when the update is done */ uploadToServer)
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for helping, actually I did it with componentWillReciveProps which were making life easier